# Invoke Java command via python subprocess hangs sometimes

Tags: java, python, subprocess, freeze

I am using python 2.7.0 -2.7.7 on various machines and got the same issue.

We had python program to invoke some java commands from a tool to read data from
core dumps.
In normal case, the code works well but if the core dumps are huge, then we run into the hang issue when python program is executing the following commands:
java -classpath toolview.jar:tool.jar
-Dcom.ibm.java.diagnostics.plugins=toolcommands.jar com.java.diagnostics.tool.launcher.TOOLViewLauncher  -core badleakcore.56130  command1

Any suggestions how to debug this or workaround?  Thanks in advance.
If we run the exact same command on the command line, it will work but it also
takes a long time due to the large core dump.

```
This is the snippet of python code how we invoke java:

import logging, sys, argparse, time, platform
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

 def runTests(core, logger):
failure = []

 #command1
 msgs = ["Command: command1", "Expected: Pass without exceptions"]
 logHeader(msgs, logger)
 retlist = executeTOOL(core, "command1", logger, failure)




def executeIDDE(core, args, logger, failureList):
if platform.system().lower() == "windows":
    sep = ";"
else:
    sep = ":"

cp = 'toolview.jar'+sep+'tool.jar'  
    cmds = 'toolcommands.jar'
plugin = '-Dcom.ibm.java.diagnostics.plugins'
main = 'com.java.diagnostics.view.launcher.TOOLViewLauncher'
cmd = 'java -classpath ' + cp + ' ' + plugin + '=' + cmds + ' '
    +    main    + '  -core ' + core + ' ' + args
    print(cmd)
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: The more interesting part is the code you haven't shown. After you create the `Popen` object, what do you do? My guess is that, when the output from the Java program is too large, you end up blocking on a full buffer and you get a hang because the subprocess won't exit until it finishes flushing its buffers.

Comment: Thank for your reply. That may be the issue, but if I increase the java heap size, the results did come back.  ie.    cmd = 'java -classpath ' + cp + ' ' + plugin + '=' + cmds + ' '
    +    main    + '  -core ' + core + ' ' + args
    print(cmd)